# Adding shapefile causes ArcMap Drawing Errors (General function failure)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, shapefile, arcgis-desktop

I am creating a map that is a hodgepodge of databases, stand alone shapefiles, and a couple image services. Everything seems to go as expected until I add a certain shapefile to the mix. Then all of the other shapefiles disappear. Once that layer is removed from the map, everything else is fine. Only shapefiles are affected. The shapefile in question (as well as all others) display properly in 9.3. And, I'm adding other data that displays from the same folder, so it's not that I'm unable to access it. I've searched for similar incidents, but have came up empty.

A similar situation happens when moving the extent (10.7.1). I checked the projection and the geographic coordinate system. Everything matches the data frame. There are two File GDBs. error appears to only happen in the one that has data copied from a different GDB. The projection and geographic coordinate system are also the same for the GDB I'm copying from.

[image]

Comment: What is the name of your shapefile?  Is it listed in your graphic?

Comment: One of your shapefiles has the wrong transformation in the projection. The first shapefile added sets the projection

Comment: The question is hard to answer with the information given. I've seen errors like this with bad indexes or bad geometry. Try Remove Spatial Index then Add Spatial Index and Check Geometry and Repair Geometry. The tools for this are in the Data Management Toolbox under Indexes and Features.

Comment: Mapperz - the shapefile has a different projection (WGS_94) than the first ones in the map (NAD 83 FT). However, other shapefiles are correctly drawn in WGS_94 and don't cause problems. And I hate the whole "but I've always done it this way", but the map that I'm working with is created from layers that all work together in 9.3 without issue. It looks like I'm going to have to go to a 9.3 machine and try to transform the layers. As I've tried that this morning as well in 10 and received errors. Will report back with what I find.

Comment: If you start a new map and add just the troublesome shapefile to it (and not from a layer file) does it draw as expected?  You've almost certainly tried this but I can't see that test mentioned above and it could indicate absence/presence of some sort of corruption in your shapefile.

Comment: Sean - I have repaired and checked geometry in 9.3. I'm going to try to remove/add spatial index today.

Comment: PolyGeo - Have added the shapefile to a fresh map. Same error as above. Then all subsequent shapefiles that are added give the same error. Any data added from a geodatabase is not affected. Also, this shapefile is used currently in 9.3 with no problems. I am working on a map for a vendor that needs to be in 10, as it is connecting to some gdbs created in 10. Otherwise my solution would be to just create this in 9.3, since that works ;)

Comment: I don't think this could be the problem but try renaming the .prj file then adding the data. If that works, please post the contents of the prj file here.

Comment: ArcGIS 9.3 handled mismatched coordinate systems differently to ArcGIS 10: the transformation MUST be supplied. I suspect the problem is in the transformation method. If possible try to project the data to the same coordinate system as the rest of the data, if not I hope there is an alternative transformation WGS_94 (is that WGS84?) to NAD 83 FT. Alternately the coordinate system may not be 'well defined', just because it says WGS in the name doesn't mean ArcGIS recognizes that, to ensure good definition reset it in Catalog using ArcGIS coordinate systems.